# My Windows pc does not recognize by usb my Ubuntu external hdd disk

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, compatibility

My old laptop had Ubuntu but it got destroyed. The HDD from that laptop is on my hands in a very good condition. However, it is not readable via usb. I don't want to format the drive yet, because I need to save something from this drive using my Windows 10 PC.

Comment: Please clarify what it is you are doing. How is the hard drive attached to the Windows PC?

Comment: Windows cannot read Linux partitions. You will need either a virtual machine or boot into a Live Session with a second USB device.

Comment: David - attached by usb in a normal way like an external hhd disk. Its in a good health. I can read that external disk using linux system but not using windows system.

Comment: I would use a live USB session on your Windows PC: create a Ubuntu installation USB ISO; boot into it selecting 'try Ubuntu'. Then attach your retrieved SSD; mount the HDD in your Windows PC and copy the files you want to keep from the SSD to the HDD. Once you've got everything you want to keep off the SSD, you can format it as NTFS and use it with your Windows computer (internal second drive if there's a slot, or with your caddy as an external drive) ...  or better still, put Ubuntu on your desktop PC instead of or as well as Windows!

Answer (score 2):

Windows sadly can't read UNIX partitions. There is software you can download to help with that issue but une of the simpler ways is to create a Linux virtual machine with for example Virtual Box + Debian/Ubuntu and read the drive from there and copy/paste the files out of the VM onto your physical machine.
You can look up how virtual box VM works on Youtube. There you can find detailed video tutorials on how to setup a VM on your Windows PC and run Ubuntu on it. From there on out, you should be able to copy all files you need from your Linux HDD.

If you are a bit skilled with the shell/bash command line, you can also use WSL2  on your Windows PC (basically installing Linux "as an app"). There you can mount said drive into the virtual file system and copy the files from it to your Windows host.
You can install WSL by just typing `wsl --install` in powershell and it will install it for you. Then you can just search for ubuntu with Windows search and it will show you the Ubuntu command line bash.
With that tool you can then mount and copy the drive that you attached via USB.

EDIT:
Also running a Ubuntu live session like @Will described in a comment under your post is a good idea. Probably even better than mine because it's hackin easy, assuming you are relatively new to IT stuff. Just load up a USB stick with a Ubuntu live image (.iso) via the programs Rufus or Etcher and then boot from that stick.

Comment: Thanks a lot actually looking for that software. The hard thing is to create a linux participation for that i need to do or a virtual machine. There is an easier way by using a software or a commant line ?